# Can a subdocument be required in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to have nested schemas in mongoose and have a required validator on the children? Something like this:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  host: {
    type: userSchema,
    required: true
  }
});
```

I can't find anything in the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this and get a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, your schema is correct.

The docs for mongoose nested schema (SubDocuments) can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

Comment: SubDocuments work the same a regular documents, the only difference is how you access them

Comment: Apparently, sub-documents are validated only if you run a `save()` on the parent document. If you run any kind of `update` in the parent, the sub-document won't be validated. Take a look at this case: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5234 and: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html -> "Validation is middleware. Mongoose registers validation as a pre('save') hook on every schema by default.". But, "You can manually run validation using doc.validate(callback) or doc.validateSync()"

Comment: I know this is old but thank you @maganap. I was driving myself crazy trying to figure out why my validations weren't working. Weird behavior.

Comment: @buckeyeguyy Good to confirm this is still the behaviour some years later. I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

i suppose you'll update eventSchema with subdocuments of type user model.
you can use `{ runValidators: true}` for update.

```
eventModel.update({ name: 'YOUR NAME' }, { $push: { host: user } }, { runValidators: true}, function(err) {

})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the nested schema in mongoose.

It will also give you he Object Id on each sub schema values as well.

- Doc: [Here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)
- Example: [Here](https://github.com/PankajJatav/posistAss/blob/master/app/models/customer.js)

Answer (score 0):

required is a validator added to a schema or subschema in Mongoose ([from docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required))
so yes, you can set the required field to true ( it is false by default) for your subschema or subdocument in Mongoose.
The example schema you have created is correct.